# Why the total loss of a Deep Learning model can abruptly become NaN using Keras (Python)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a Keras (TF2.0 backend) model that uses multiple loss values for backpropagation. As the training is initialized the model appears to gradually learn (Clear indication of loss decreasing over epochs).

However, at some random epoch, the total loss suddenly becomes NaN. In the following epoch, some of my individual losses also become constant at 0.000. The behavior is not deterministic. Sometimes, the model runs the entire 100 epochs without becoming NaN.

**How can total loss ever become NaN when the individual losses are finite numbers?**

So my question is more conceptual than programming. Any reasons why this may happen? The obvious candidate to look at would be the custom_loss_function, however, as I mentioned the individual losses haven't become NaN (See below for example).

Here I am showing the loss over 4 randomly picked epochs in a training cycle:

```
--------------------------------------------------
STARTING EPOCH: 0
        loss:7.612e-01, 
   xout_loss:7.606e-01, 
 yout_0_loss:0.000e+00,  yout_1_loss:1.673e-04,  yout_2_loss:4.342e-04,  yout_3_loss:3.220e-05,
...
--------------------------------------------------
STARTING EPOCH: 10
        loss:3.355e-02, 
   xout_loss:3.349e-02, 
 yout_0_loss:0.000e+00,  yout_1_loss:0.000e+00,  yout_2_loss:6.202e-05,  yout_3_loss:0.000e+00,
...
--------------------------------------------------
STARTING EPOCH: 20
        loss:3.294e-02, 
   xout_loss:3.289e-02, 
 yout_0_loss:0.000e+00,  yout_1_loss:0.000e+00,  yout_2_loss:5.094e-05,  yout_3_loss:0.000e+00,
...
--------------------------------------------------
STARTING EPOCH: 47
        loss:   nan, 
   xout_loss:3.501e-03, 
 yout_0_loss:0.000e+00,  yout_1_loss:0.000e+00,  yout_2_loss:5.997e-05,  yout_3_loss:0.000e+00,
...
--------------------------------------------------
STARTING EPOCH: 48
        loss:   nan, 
   xout_loss:3.240e-02, 
 yout_0_loss:0.000e+00,  yout_1_loss:0.000e+00,  yout_2_loss:0.000e+00,  yout_3_loss:0.000e+00,
```

Note that I have looked up at a few questions asking about loss turning to NaN, but in all these cases the OP had a single loss which became NaN and had to address their loss function. The case here is different. Eg. [Keras loss becomes nan only at epoch end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52880384/1630046), [Loss of CNN in Keras becomes nan at some point of training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55051978/loss-of-cnn-in-keras-becomes-nan-at-some-point-of-training)

**UPDATE:** Loss function definition

For yout_xxx:

```
def corr_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true)
    y_pred = tf.squeeze(y_pred)

    xm = y_true - tf.reduce_mean(y_true, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    ym = y_pred - tf.reduce_mean(y_pred, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    c_num = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(xm, ym), axis=1)
    c_den = tf.math.sqrt(tf.multiply(tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(xm), axis=1), tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(ym), axis=1)))

    r = c_num / (c_den+tf.keras.backend.epsilon())
    loss = 1 - tf.math.square(r)
    return loss
```

For xout_loss:

```
tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

Comment: Something that shouldn't be zero reached zero? Then you got some `log`, or division, or another thing that can't take all zeros?

Comment: Can you specify how you implement each loss function?

Comment: But as I mentioned above, Isn't the total loss simply the sum of individual losses? In which case when those losses are finite how would the total loss become NaN. The individual losses are simply Pearson correlations (xout is mse). Let me update that.

Comment: As what daniel said, ive met the case where my loss goes to NaN when i my model is trying to minimize log prob and it ends up reaching -inf (nan) when prob = 0 (log 0 = -inf).

Comment: Yes, there is a high probability of division by zero, but I have added epsilon in the denominator to avoid this.

Comment: Did you check for log?

Comment: included the custom loss functions in my update. Do you know how the total loss is computed? It is just the sum of individual losses (weighted if loss_weights are provided). Is that right?

Comment: OK here's an update, I have replaced 'adam' optimizer with 'sgd' and also included tf.clip_by_norm(). In the last 2 runs I didn't encounter NaN. Still trying to connect the dots... Also will check over more runs to confirm

Comment: Most likely exploding gradients. This can happen even if there are no "bugs" due to complex training mechanics in deep neural networks. Also, your loss has "dangerous" operations such as divisions and square root (these can have ill-behaved gradients) You might want to reduce the number of layers or introduce normalization methods like batch normalization.